# Query to find players who represented multiple countries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table: <sup>[Sample table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNxkz.jpg)</sup>

```
PlayerID | PlayerName |Country
---------+------------+---------
1001     | Virat      | Ind
1001     | Virat      | USA
1002     | Dave       | Aus
1003     | Paul       | Ireland
1005     | Kapil      | Ind
1005     | Kapil      | Aus
1006     | Manoj      | NZ
1007     | Manish     | SA
1008     | Paul       | SriLanka
1008     | Paul       | SriLanka
1008     | Paul       | SriLanka
1004     | David      | SA
1005     | David      | SA
```

I would like to run a query from the given table to find out either `PlayerIDs` or `PlayerNames` who have represented multiple countries. For example `PlayerID=1001` have represented more than one country which is '`IND`' and '`USA`'.
There are some duplicates rows in this table, but please ignore them.

Comment: Any efforts to write such a query by yourself? Have you tried it? What problems have you faced?

Comment: 1008,1004 and 1005 are duplicates?

Comment: @Andy, yes mate! i did try a few hours to find a solution for it.I have tried using row_number , rank() functions in my query and it didnt help much

Comment: @Deepak In this case  it is always better to include your attempts into question, otherwise question looks like "please, do it for me" request which is definite offtopic at StackOverflow and can be heavily downvoted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details on how to ask a good question and good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT PlayerID, PlayerName
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY PlayerID, PlayerName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Country) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid sub-queries, CTEs, joins, cross apply etc - could try something like

```
SELECT Y.PlayerId, Y.PlayerName,COUNT(DISTINCT Y.Country) countriesPlayedFor
       FROM YourTable Y 
            GROUP BY Y.PlayerId, Y.PlayerName
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Y.Country) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also deal with the duplicates:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT PlayerID
        ,PlayerName
        ,Country
    FROM dbo.PlayerCountries
    )
SELECT PlayerName
    ,COUNT(Country)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY PlayerName
HAVING COUNT(Country) > 1
```